# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why I am getting this error?
Please help... I can't understant! It seems that I that I have an illegal access but I can't figure it out...

```
int main ()
{
    int repeat = 1;
    int comamnd = 0;

 do {
    printf ("\n\tSelect:\n1) Login\n2) Quit\n\nWhat's the command? ");
    scanf ("%d", command);
    if (command == 2)
        return 0;
    else;
    if (command == 1)
    {
        int ok = Login ();
        if (ok == 1)
            repeat = 0;
    };
    } while (repeat == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please re-read about the proper usage of semicolons. In particular, these 2 lines: `else;` and  `};`.

Comment: `int comamnd = 0;` --> `int command = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf ("%d", command);
```

You're passing a zero to `scanf` as the place to read the input. You want:

```
scanf ("%d", &command);
```

If your compiler didn't warn you, you should switch to a better compiler.